# Apache .htaccess acting strangely?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
#Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^(.*)$
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]*[a-zA-Z0-9])$   index.php?_path=$1&%1
```

Here is my file structure:

```
example.com/
 |- rewriteTest/
 |   |- images/
 |   |   |- logo.png
 |   |   |- icon.png
 |   |- style/
 |   |   |- housekeeping.css
 |   |   |- style.css
 |   |- .htaccess
 |   |- index.php
```

The desired behavior is that

```
example.com/rewriteTest/any/path
```

should point to

```
example.com/rewriteTest/index.php?_path=any/path
```

AND

```
example.com/rewriteTest/images
```

(without the leading slash) should point to

```
example.com/rewriteTest/index.php?_path=images
```

AND

```
example.com/rewriteTest/images/logo.png
```

should point to

```
example.com/rewriteTest/index.php?_path=images/logo.png
```

The rewriting works if the path is not an existing directory or file. However, if, say, I navigate to the `/images` directory, the url in my browser (Chrome) changes to `/images/?_path=images` and shows a 403 page. And if I navigate to `/images/logo.png`, the image opens up, instead of showing the page at `/index.php?_path=images/logo.png`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems to be an issue. Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rewriteTest/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)_path=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also to open a directory URL use a trailing slash like `http://domain.com/images/`

Comment: This does not work. Now I am getting a 403 Forbidden for any URL. I'm not sure if the regex is the problem, as it works for everything else. My problem is that it seems as if mod_rewrite breaks when I navigate to a path that actually exists.

Comment: Uncommenting `Options FollowSymLinks` made my index.php become Forbidden for some reason.

Comment: The `.htaccess` is located in the parent directory of images, alongside an `index.php`.

Comment: Still the same problems.

Comment: Navigating to a `/random/path` gives *Forbidden: index.php*.

Comment: Navigating to `/images` gives *Forbidden: /images*

Comment: Navigating to `/images/logo.png` gives *Forbidden: index.php*

Comment: Ok, this works better now. However, one of the issues stil remains: navigating to `example.com/rewriteTest/images` (without the slash) gives a `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /rewriteTest/images/ on this server.`

Comment: I did notice, but I want the path `/images` without the leading slash to also point to `index.php`. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Try `DirectorySlash off` at top of .htaccess

Comment: This did not affect behavior

Comment: I was hoping to make it so that any possible path would point to `index.php`, and then I would everything in one place, where I could parse the path myself and have complete control over everything.

Comment: First of all not using trailing slash in front of directories is unsecure so you are better off not using it. 2nd above rules work fine on my Apache.